# Redirect VPN through one interface and "the internet" through another

Tags: mac, vpn, routing

This is my network architecture right now:

- Interface 1 (en0): medium speed unlimited download wi-fi network
- Interface 2 (en6): fast speed limited download 4G hotspot

I have to access an VPN (vtun0) to work. 
But using the Wi-fi network is barely impossible due speed and other things. Gladly, the 4G hotspot works pretty well with the VPN. Unfortunately, since I have a limited download with the hotspot, so I don't wanna "waste it" with mail and random internet access.

So what want is:

- Connect VPN through the 4g hotspot, and the VPN ONLY.
- All other connections through the Wi-Fi.

I've read some solutions to do this with `iptables` like (not sure about syntax or anything):

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i utun0 -o en6 -j ACCEPT
```

I'm using a MAC OS X Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to use the VPN to access your work subnet **only**, and to use your wifi for anything else, then it can be done.

The simplest way to set this up is:

1.Connect via 4G;

2.Start the VPN connection;

3.Start the wifi connection.

To check on this, let us suppose your home LAN  is 192.168.1.0/24, your work LAN is 192.168.10.0/24, and your 4G LAN is 192.168.0.0/24. Should any two of these three subnets coincide, you will have a major problem.

How do you check it? Issue the command *ifconfig*; this will show the IP addresses of en0, en6, vtun0: it's the number immediately after *inet*. I repeat, they **must** belong to different subnets. If they do not, you will have to change your home's subnet to prevent conflicts.

To check the configuration, the routing table (displayed by *netstat -nr*) you wish to have is:

1.**Only one** default gateway, pointing to your home's gateway on the device (called *netif* in the routing table) en0; the default gateway is identified by the line with the field *default* under *Destination*, or, alternatively, by the flag *G* uder *Flags*.

2.One gateway (but **not** default) for each of your home, work, and 4G subnets.

No matter what the situation is, you will surely have the gateways at bullet 2 above. The whole point is whether the default gateway is your home's gateway, or not.

*If it is not*, you redress the situation by deleting the old gateway,

```
  sudo route delete default
```

and establishing your home gateway as the *default  gateway*:

```
  sudo route add default 192.168.1.1
```

if your home gateway is indeed 192.168.1.1, otherwise change it accordingly.

Comment: Thx for the help man! But my route table is a little odd... I have 3 default gateways, one for each of the connections. When trying to do the delete-add, it deleted the 4G default...

Comment: @Rodrigo can you pls post it? Just the IPv4 part, I guess.

Comment: `Destination        Gateway                Netif`
`default            177.168.192.*          en6`
`default            10.97.169.*            en0`
`default            utun0                 utun0`

Comment: @Rodrigo Please post the whole output of netstat -nr in your OP, ty.